# The Princes in the Tower

Tags: murder

This (long) argument about the murders of the boy-king, Edward V, and his brother, Richard (Duke of York) in (around) September 1483 continues. Many opine (including members of "The Richard III Society") that Richard of Gloucester/ Richard III was not responsible for the deaths of his nephews.

My question is this: given that he, Richard, put the boys in the Tower; held them there; controlled all access to them; then, he, Richard, was responsible for anything that happened to them, even if he was a 1000-miles away, at the time, wasn't he?

What would contemporary law say? Would it be any different from the law in the 15th. Century--how would one find that out?

Comment: Can't we say something similar about any small child?  They don't leave home except with their parent's permission, and their parent similarly controls all access.  Does it follow that whenever a small child is harmed, no matter how or by whom, the parent is automatically (legally) responsible?

Comment: @Nate Eldridge: If the child is a prisoner, in one building, and only one person controls all their movements and all access to that child; then, what do you think?

Comment: You realize that under 15th century law he king cold often just declare someone guilty of any capital crime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### People die with no one responsible

Fatal accidents and illnesses are a thing, even in the 21st century, let alone the 15th. We don't hold guardians (or jailors) responsible for such deaths.

The Tower of London was a 400-year-old building at the time, and 11th-century building codes were light on in the safety department. When you visit the tower today, you access some areas by 20th-century staircases because the original ones can't be made safe. It's easy to see two adolescent boys playing as knights taking a tragic and fatal tumble down the staircase. On not playing, at that age, these boys would have been well into their training at arms - with real swords in mock battles; that's hella dangerous.

Encephalitis is often fatal today. Do you know what was also fatal in the 14th century? *Everything*. No antibiotics, no antiseptics, no refrigeration. So many ways to get sick and die.

So, no, merely being responsible for the boys would not make Richard necessarily responsible for their deaths.

### Could he be convicted of murder today?

Yes.

He had motive, and opportunity, and he must have known how they died (if, in fact they died before he did - which seems most likely). People have been convicted on less.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149245/discussion-on-answer-by-dale-m-the-princes-in-the-tower); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.